# I am trying to change image at regular intervals with showing progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change image at regular intervals.First it shows some progress bar running, When progress bar finishes the image will be changed and it goes on again and again.I am achieving this by css animation and javascript.My problem if I console.log() the animation is working if i remove console.log() the animation plays only once.

```js
let circle = $('.round');
let avatars = $('.avatars');
let i = 1;
let imageArray = [
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyxho.jpg',
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyxho.jpg',
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyxho.jpg'
];

circle.on('animationend',function(){
    $(this).css('animation','none');
    console.log($(this).css('animation'));
    avatars.attr('src',imageArray[i]);
    $(this).css('animation','fill 5s linear 2s');
    console.log($(this).css('animation'));
    if(i < imageArray.length){ 
        i++; 
    }else{ 
        i=0; 
    } 
});
```

```css
#home .container svg{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#home .container svg .round{
    stroke-dasharray: 534;
    stroke-dashoffset: 534;
    animation: fill 5s linear 2s;
}
#home .container .img{
    width: 170px;
    height:170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#home .container img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
    <div class="container">
        <svg width='172' height='172'>
            <circle class='round' r='85' cx='86' cy='86' stroke-width='2' stroke='white' fill='none' />
        </svg>
        <div class="img">
            <img class='avatars' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyxho.jpg" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <h1>Bla Bla</h1>
        <span id='typed'></span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I didn't understood?

Comment: Why its so happening?